# comma right after a comma or not?

Tags: commas

> Because of that, at this point, they should do it.

I am thinking this is ok, but is this ok?

> Because of that, at this point they should do it.

I see people do it often, but I think it's just a grammar error, so I am wondering if there's any rule that says it's ok since there's already "because of that" with a comma.

Comment: My inclination would be to drop the "at this point" entirely. Possibly I would add the word "now" at the end of the sentence. But that does not answer your question.

Comment: Could you please provide additional context?

Answer (score 1):

> Because of that, at this point, they should do it.

The above example is fine.  *at this point* could be treated as an interruption and could hence be separated by a comma pair.

> Because of that, at this point they should do it.

*Because of that* and *at this point* are introductory prepositional phrases.

Please refer to [Englishplus](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000074.htm) for the following example.

> Correct: Over hill, over dale, we hit the dusty trail.
> (The two phrases are in series here. We could say "Over hill and over dale.")

Our two phrases are considered parallel and hence should be separated by a comma.

Similar to cases where we place a comma after the last introductory phrase, we should have a comma here after *at this point*.

> Because of that, at this point, they should do it.

By adding an **and** between the two phrases, we could show that *Because of that* and *at this point* are parallel.

> Because of that and at this point, they should do it.

I believe we could test also by swapping the positions of the two phrases.

> At this point, because of that, they should do it.

The sentence is still fine.

Answer (score 0):

That first example is what's called a "comma splice"

See the heading "comma splice" here:
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma/

The second example you wrote is better but to my native American eyes it seems awkward.

Good question.

Comment: Not sure that it's a comma splice. If it were then you could make two sentences. I don't think there is a second sentence.

Comment: It is certainly *not* a comma splice, which describes the misconjunction of two independent clauses—as your Grammarly citation indicates. OP's sentence contains exactly one clause. Even if the first were a clause, the subordinating clause "because" would make it dependent.